# How to load dynamically created img element with jquery into HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I cannot load/ display image created with jquery on HTML5 canvas but it works when image object is created as =  new Image();

In particular, using this script as example: https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-invert-image-colors-tutorial/

but substituting img source with:

`imageObj.src = 'https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nasa%3Abluemarble&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=0,2504688.542848655,2504688.5428486555,5009377.085697314';`

and adding attribute:  `imageObj.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`

just after: `var imageObj = new Image();`

it allows for editing function to run and the image draws on canvas.

However, by creating the image with the following jquery, the image is not displayed in canvas and no errors are reported in the console:

```
var imageObj = $("<img />",
{ 
crossOrigin: "Anonymous", 
src: "https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nasa%3Abluemarble&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=0,2504688.542848655,2504688.5428486555,5009377.085697314"  
});
```

Am I missing a step that binds img to document or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the image creation in the example code you forgot the load event. Hence, your code should be:

```
var imageObj = $("<img />", {
    crossOrigin: "Anonymous",
    src: "https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nasa%3Abluemarble&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=0,2504688.542848655,2504688.5428486555,5009377.085697314"
}).on('load', function (e) {
    drawImage(this);
});
```

```js
var imageObj = $("<img />", {
    crossOrigin: "Anonymous",
    src: "https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=nasa%3Abluemarble&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=0,2504688.542848655,2504688.5428486555,5009377.085697314"
}).on('load', function (e) {
    drawImage(this);
});


function drawImage(imageObj) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = 69;
    var y = 50;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        // red
        data[i] = 255 - data[i];
        // green
        data[i + 1] = 255 - data[i + 1];
        // blue
        data[i + 2] = 255 - data[i + 2];
    }

    // overwrite original image
    context.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! For my sanity, the original code had this: imageObj.onload= function(){ drawImage(this);};  so why it did not fire?

Comment: So, can "load" part be separated? The reason I am asking is because I need to add a few more functions, to run in sequence, before drawing on canvas. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but like you can see the load part is by itself so short.... You may instead create a function with an argument (the url)...... Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot.